# Tick labels only displayed in one subplot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Need to display custom shared x-axis tick labels on both subplots, using two datasets with different dates.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, date_range, Timedelta
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#Dataset 1
rng1 = date_range(start='01-01-2015', periods=5, freq='1M')
df1 = DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(size=len(rng1))}, index=rng1)
y1 = df1['y']

#Dataset 2
rng2 = date_range(start='01-01-2015', periods=5, freq='2M')
df2 = DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(size=len(rng2))}, index=rng2)
y2 = df2['y']

#Figure
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True)

y1.plot(ax=ax1)
y2.plot(ax=ax2)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())

ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%D'))

plt.show()
```

(Above) Creates figure without x-axis labels on the upper subplot

I expect adding the below code to display the same x-axis labels to the upper subplot, but they are not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

```
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%D'))
```

Setting sharex=False does not work because the dates are different for each dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use `matplotlib.dates` locators and formatters on a plot created via pandas you should use the `x_compat=True` argument in your plot, otherwise pandas may scale the axis rather arbitrarily.

Then `'%D'` is not a valid format string. Maybe you mean `'%b'`?

Now there are two options.

- Use `sharex=False`, set your locators and formatters to both axes, and finally set the limits of the one plot to the limits of the other. In this case since the lower plot comprises a larger range,

  ```
  ax1.set_xlim(ax2.get_xlim())
  ```
- The other option is to use `sharex=True` and turn the labels visible again.

  ```
  plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
  ```

  Unfortunately this option is broken on the newest matplotlib version. I just [opened a bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10911) about it.

Full code for the first option (since the second one is not working):

```
from pandas import DataFrame, date_range, Timedelta
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#Dataset 1
rng1 = date_range(start='2015-01-01', periods=5, freq='1M')
df1 = DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(size=len(rng1))}, index=rng1)
y1 = df1['y']

#Dataset 2
rng2 = date_range(start='2015-01-01', periods=5, freq='2M')
df2 = DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(size=len(rng2))}, index=rng2)
y2 = df2['y']

#Figure
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=False)

y1.plot(ax=ax1, x_compat=True)
y2.plot(ax=ax2, x_compat=True)

plt.xticks(rotation=30)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.NullLocator())
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))

ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.NullLocator())
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))

ax1.set_xlim(ax2.get_xlim())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I use a `dataframe.plot(subplots=True)` to plot multiple plots with same dataframe. All multiple plots have different yaxis range. So `sharey` is not possible. How do I format yaxis ticks for each subplot axis? `plt.gca()` only gets me last subplot axis. And any formatting such as `.set_major_formatter()` affects only last subplot. How to do that for all subplots?

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me, just following the [shared_axis_demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html)

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
_ = plt.plot(y1)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)

ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
_ = plt.plot(y2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you can throw in `ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%D'))` right above the `plt.show()` to get it formatted correctly. Oddly, I cannot get both axes to rotate. I can either get the top axis to rotate only, or if I try to rotate the bottom, they both disappear. Hopefully just make the fonts appropriate and ticks sparse enough that you don't have to rotate them.

Comment: I add `plt.xticks(rotation=30)` and it rotates the labels on ax2. Then add `rotation=30` within `plt.setp()` to rotate ax1 labels.

Comment: I use a dataframe.plot(subplots=True) to plot multiple plots with same dataframe. All multiple plots have different yaxis range. So sharey is not possible. How do I format yaxis ticks for each subplot axis? plt.gca() only gets me last subplot axis. And any formatting such as .set_major_formatter() affects only last subplot. How to do that for all subplots?

Comment: @Meet don't use `DataFrame.plot` then. It's a great method, but has its limitations, If you need to really customize your figures then it's best to set up the matplotlib ax objects and use DataFrame.plot to plot on the specific axes you want.